# How to call a variable from one function inside another function?

Tags: python

I have one function `load`

```
  def load():
        file = open((input("File name: ")), "r")
        movies_list = file.readlines()
        movies_list = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
        file.close()
```

And I want to use the list `movies_list` in another function `randomSelection`

```
def randomSelection():
         print(random.choice(movies_list))
```

How can I get around this? Is there a way to declare `movies_list` as a global variable?

Comment: define `movie_list` as global.

Comment: Why not return `movies_list` from `load` and pass to `randomSelection`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement

Comment: Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 8):

Return `movies_list` and pass it as an argument to `randomSelection`.

```
def load():
    with open((input("File name: ")), "r") as file:
        movies_list = file.readlines()
        movies_list = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
    return movies_list

def randomSelection(movies_list):
     print(random.choice(movies_list))

movies_list = load()
randomSelection(movies_list)
```

Comment: This would return an error when load() function is executed. check the code

Comment: Which error? What do you mean?

Comment: remove the colon(:) while executing load() function

Comment: @ManiKandan OK, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can either return the movies_list and pass as arg to another function (or) use global variable

You can define a movie_list as a global variable as follows:

```
def load():
        file = open((input("File name: ")), "r")
        global movies_list
        movies_list = file.readlines()
        movies_list = [movie.strip() for movie in movies_list]
        file.close()
```

Then you can use the movies_list after the load() function is executed

```
load()
def randomSelection():
         print(random.choice(movies_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are okay. Another option is defining your methods inside a class and using instance variable for sharing data between them:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie_list = "Empty"

    def f1(self):
        self.movie_list = "God_Father"

    def f2(self):
        print self.movie_list


test = Test()
test.f2()
test.f1()
test.f2()
```

Output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Empty
God_Father
>>>
```

Comment: Sounds like overkill.

Comment: @DisplayName OOP is preferred I guess. No?

Comment: Why do you think so? Python is a multi paradigm language: procedural, functionla, OO.